# spam attack...is there anything else that the community can do to help the moderators?

Tags: support, feature-request, spam

I feel that recently we are fighting more with the spammers. But is flagging enough to help the moderators? any other measure we can do? I don't know something like when you flag and it is trusted user with certain number of accepted flags...can delete the user automatically? It might be a bad idea. But I wish I could do more about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that was weird, about 4 spam posts from newly registered accounts in the space of about half an hour, and I think some earlier today as well. I destroyed a few accounts and other mods have taken action too so it's all been cleared up.

Personally I think flagging's enough at the moment, while it's unsavoury to see spam it's not a massive problem on this site. We mods get an icon in the toolbar telling us how many mod flags there are outstanding, so it's rare that a post flagged as spam will be around for long.

There are already automatic bans in place for users who reach a certain level of deleted/downvoted content, but I don't think they kick in very often for spammers as their accounts just aren't around for long enough.

Comment: And in a wonderful irony, another one's been posted as I was writing this.

Comment: Yeah, flagging is probably sufficient.  The mods here have a decent spread of timezone differences, so the coverage is good.  Even when I am busy, I check flags periodically to take care of immediate needs, and handling spam is very easy (and required not thinking/judgement).

Comment: Seems to be getting worse!!

Comment: seems to be worse on weekends or when there is football or big game coming :S

Answer (score 4):

Just to reinforce one aspect, please **just** flag spam as spam.  Please

- Don't use any flags, other than spam.
- Don't edit to remove links.
- Don't re-tag as spam.

These three actions can interfere with the spam gets handled.  Fore more information, read [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work) over on MSO.

Comment: Are there exceptions not using any other flags besides the spam flag? What about when a post is *definitely* spam, but *not obviously so*, ...or is obviously spam but there is an additional issue warranting moderator attention? Is it appropriate to flag as spam and *also* use a custom flag, in these instances? (I've found such action to be well received on several other SE sites, but I appreciate if the guidelines/rules are different here.) I'll post a separate meta question about this if you like, but I suspect this could be fully addressed by clarification (or "even if" affirmation) here.

Comment: @EliahKagan The spam flag carries an automatic downvote, and enough spam will remove the post from the front page and delete it.  I would reserve the custom flag for cases where the author is shamelessly self promoting and you want to give the mods some more info.

Comment: this new spam attack is weird there are from new members and they have been members for 4 days or 2 days at least...

Comment: The SE people think it is a meatnet and not automated spambots.  That makes it harder to deal with.